# When form validation fails how to redirect to different function based on inputs

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a input page with 3 inputs username, password, OTP. When password is wrong i want to send it 1 function and if OTP fails i want to send it other function. How can i achieve this. Below is a sample code.

```
   public function verifyLogin() {
            $data['BASE_URL'] = base_url();
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('otp', 'OTP', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_check_otpNum');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
                if(//passwordFails)
                    $this->index();
                else if(//otpfails)
                    $this->loginPage(); 

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **$this->form_validation->error_array()** to get all failed validations and then equating accordingly

Comment: I get this error when doing that "Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::error_array() in D:\xampp\htdocs\sample\application\controllers\userLog.php on line 106"

Comment: <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> try this to get errors.if it works